# Is it possible for a visual studio debug visualizer (natvis) to perform a map lookup?

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

So I have a type, which is used as a key into a map. The key itself isn't particularly human readable (e.g. a 128 bit guid), but the value in the map that this key references, is.

Is it possible, without modifying the code (I've seen methods used that add additional data purely for the debug visualizers to hook into), to add a type definition to the natvis for my key type, that searches the map for the entry associated with my key?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that can be used as a starting point to write the natvis for.